# NHibernate: Parameter in Formula

Tags: nhibernate

I have folling property in my mapping:

```
<id name="Id" column="ID" type="int" unsaved-value="0">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
<property name="HaveData" formula="(dbo.fnGetData(Id, :dateTime))" type="bool" update="false" insert="false"/>
```

I would like to do a session.CreateCriteria and set the parameter ":dateTime". I've tried to work with filters, but without success.

Is it this possible to have parameter in formula and how?

Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

What did not success in using filters?
Here you have a samples of how to use filters:

http://ayende.com/blog/3993/nhibernate-filters

http://ayende.com/blog/1954/localizing-nhibernate-contextual-parameters

Comment: "Please note that this is no longer supported behavior in NHibernate 2.1 and up" => http://ayende.com/blog/1954/localizing-nhibernate-contextual-parameters